# Can spaceship operator be used in fold expressions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, fold-expression, spaceship-operator

None of the compilers I [tried](https://godbolt.org/z/nf8f3sjaa) accept such code:

`template <int ...a> bool foo() { return (a<=> ... <=>0); }`

But for any other `<=,>=,==,!=,<,>` it compiles.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) is clear here - there is no `<=>` on the list of binary operators we can use for fold expression.

Is this an intentional omission in the C++ standard, or are compilers not ready with this?

The question is just pure curiosity; I just wanted to know what the C++ direction is in this area. I can imagine all other compare operators will be removed from the fold-expression list of allowed operators, as they have as much sense as `<=>` in a fold expression...

Comment: "But for any other `<=,>=,==,!=,<,>` it works."  [It has been proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0313r0.html) that **all** comparison operators be removed from fold expressions, as their meanings are very unintuitive.  After the first comparison, you would be comparing all other values against a `bool`.

Comment: I wonder: what should be outcome for `return (a<=> ... <=>0);`? What kind of code it should generate? Can you provide also working example for `<=` which make sense?

Comment: "But for any other `<=,>=,==,!=,<,>` it **works**." I wouldn't say it *works*, I would say it simply compiles.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is intentional.

The problem with fold-expanding comparison operators is that it works by doing this: `A < B < C < D`. This is only meaningfully useful in circumstances where `operator<` has been overloaded to mean something *other than* comparison. This is why [an attempt was made to stop C++17 from allowing you to fold over them in the first place](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0313r0.html).

`operator<=>` is *never* supposed to be used for something other than comparison. So it is forbidden.